# What process am I using?

Tags: modeling, simulation

I hope someone can help me with terminology.

I have a hobby project where I transform baseball season statistics to a card game, making player-cards that (as best as possible given the domain restrictions) represent real-life. I have some equations that synthesize/process/map real-life statistics to player-card values. This process involves generating sample player-cards (from a pre-defined distribution) to calculate against. That is, when I'm determining the optimum values of a certain player-card-batter given his real-life data, I need a set of player-card-pitchers against which to calculate his card-game performance. I try some defined number of possible values for the player-card-batter and pick the one that most closely (sum of squared error over attributes) matches real-life statistics.

Without knowledge of the statistics field, I've thought of this process as modelling with a monte-carlo simulation. I would like to know the name of the process I'm using, and how I could improve my model, as I'm trying to generate the most true-to-life player-cards as possible.

Let me know if I need to describe the algorithm in more detail, or otherwise how I can make this question more clear.